# Python thinks file is still a .py when it is .exe

Tags: python, operating-system

Got some weird behavior here. Basically I am using `import os` to find the path of the exe file and then I use that path in a batch file to move the exe file. I've also used pyinstaller to make the program an exe.

Now here is where the issue occurs. The os commands works well, but it thinks the file is still a .py
This is really odd because I made this variable:

```
dirName = os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

Now, this finds the correct directory and the correct file name(but not file type)
Then I use that variable to write down which directory the file is currently in like this:

```
move.write('move /Y "' + str(dirName) + '" (code continues here, but not important)
```

This works when the file is a .py but not when it is a .exe

I hope this makes sense, feel free to ask and/or edit if anything is unclear.

Current output: The system cannot find the file specified.
Wanted output: 1 file(s) moved.

Comment: Can you post the current and wanted output?

Comment: Additional information have been added

Comment: Also it might be worth mentioning that the output comes from the batch file, not the python file

Comment: I meant the outcome of dirName. Is just the '.py' that needs to change to '.exe'? Then you can use str.replace, re or pathlib.Path

Comment: Ahh, so basically the output of dirName is C:\path\path\path\Program.py. This is really odd because the "Program.py" is actually an exe file.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=__file__#__file__  `__file__` is probably the full path of the .py file from which the exe was made.  You could check the documentation for whatever pyinstaller.  And try `print __cached__`

Comment: oh yeah, try sys.argv[0] as well.  I would post an answer, but I don't have pyinstaller, and I don't like to post untested answers.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I managed to find a quck and easy solution. Basically I had the full path with the file, but I used something else to find only the directory it was in and put the .exe in there manually so it knows what to move.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the extension you want by this way:

```
files = os.listdir('/your/directory')
for filename in files:
    if filename.endswith(".exe"):#or extension you want
        #copy file you want
```